# CLR20r3 when running C# app on another PC

Tags: c#, .net

I made an app using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and C#.NET language and when I tried to run it on another PC it just crashes and says your program stopped working. Here is what I get when I click on Problem details:

`Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: evidencija.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 55856665
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4ba1da6f
  Problem Signature 07: 105d
  Problem Signature 08: 1c
  Problem Signature 09: PSZQOADHX1U5ZAHBHOHGHLDGIY4QIXHX
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    5146
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789`

It works with no problem on the computer where I programmed it, but on any other PC it shows an error above. I installed .Net Framework 4.0 but no luck, still the same. Any advices how to solve this?

Event Viewer shows this:

> Application: evidencija.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
>   The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
>   Info: System.TypeInitializationException Stack: at
>   fingerprint.Form1..ctor() at fingerprint.Program.Main()

Comment: We are missing the actual exception. It should be there in the call stack.

Comment: I cannot find it. This is what I get when I click View problem details on "Program stopped working" dialog... there is nothing else written over there. Is there any way how I can get some more info about it?

Comment: To run an application on another computer one of the following must occur : 1) The exact same version of net library (including updates) must be installed on both computers. 2) You must deploy the application.  Use the menu option publish (use CD option) and build an installation folder with setup.exe in root folder.  The install like any commercial purchased software product.

Comment: @TestUser Check the event log

Comment: That's how I already tried to make an installation file and installation goes well, but at the end, when it tries to start the program, i got that error. When I open Event Viewer on machine where crash occurs, here is what it says: Application: evidencija.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException Stack: at fingerprint.Form1..ctor() at fingerprint.Program.Main()

Comment: That usually means a missing reference somewhere.

Comment: That was when I tried to run Debug version on another machines. And this is what is happened when I run Release x86 version: http://i.imgur.com/PvNZC9a.png